# C++ summing multiples of 3 and 5

Tags: c++

I just started C++ programming for three days now and I cannot figure out how to complete this exercise. Basically, I want to sum all multiples of 3 and 5 under 1000. Here is my code:

```
int sum3n5(int max){

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= max; ++i){

        if( i%3 == 0 && i%5 == 0 ) { sum += i;}

        else if( i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0 ) { sum +=i;} 

    return sum;       

    };    
};
```

Sorry if it is a trivial mistake that I failed to realize. 
I always get the result 0 after running this.

Comment: You `return` after the first `if`, so `sum` is `0` because you have not hit any values of `i` that would update it yet. Move the `return` to be after the end of the loop.

Comment: BTW the first test is redundant, seeing as both cases do the same thing

Comment: Note also that it can be done without loop with some math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int sum3n5(int max){

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= max; ++i){

        if( i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 ){
            sum += i;
        }

    }

    return sum;       
}
```

You only need the `||` (logical or) operator, not the `&&` (and certainly not both!). And the `return` needs to be *after* the for loop so that the loop can complete before the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

A version without loop:

```
int sum3n5(int max)
{
    return 3 * (max / 3) * (max / 3 + 1) / 2
        + 5 * (max / 5) * (max / 5 + 1) / 2
        - 15 * (max / 15) * (max / 15 + 1) / 2;
}
```

It uses the fact that `1 + 2 + .. + n == n * (n + 1) / 2`